# Hibernate dialect not defined error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, connection, persistence

I have been facing this issue with my application and do not know what is wrong:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AuditEventManager' defined in class path resource [manager-service.xml]: Cannot resol
ve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '
transactionManager' defined in class path resource [manager-persistence-StandAlone.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exceptio
n is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [manager-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
 nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection avalable
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at MSImport.Import.main(Import.java:567)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [manager-persistence-StandAlone.xml]: Cannot resol
ve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionF
actory' defined in class path resource [manager-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connec
tion avalable
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [manager-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method f
ailed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection avalable
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection avalable
        at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:134)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2119)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2115)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1339)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
        ... 41 more
```

Comment: Have you provided a dialect for your database?

Comment: no. I am always supposed to have a DB connectivity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sometimes happens if you can't connect to the database, or hibernate can't work out which dialect to use. The important bit is:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available
```

If you don't specifically provide a database dialect, hibernate tries to work out the dialect to use using metadata returned from the jdbc driver. However, if it can't connect to the database, or for some reason it can't find the metadata, then it can't do this, and you get this message.

1. Check your database connection url, and make sure the database is available, and check the jdbc driver class is specified correctly.
2. In general, specify your hibernate dialect, to avoid problems. See [Hibernate Session Configuration - Optional Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional).

Comment: actually the problem was that I did not put the right entries in the jdbc.properties

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue that resulted in that exception as well.  My issue was that I did not have the mysql connector installed properly so Tomcat couldn't load my connection. I'm using an Ubuntu server with OpenJDK.

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-java
sudo ln -s /usr/share/maven-repo/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.16/mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/mysql-connector-java.jar
```